# Collecting the Azure Diagnosis Log Remotely without the support of Storage Account

Tags: performance, logging, azure, diagnostics

I have a use case where I need the **Diagnostics** and Performance data of the Azure Web-Role to be monitored remotely which is to be done without any Storage Account.

[image: Azure Remote Data Monitoring]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding to Stuart's answer: the Diagnostic Monitor is set up to collect counters, logs, and diagnostics locally and aggregate them into well-known Azure Storage tables, so this requires a storage account. If you wrote a background process to periodically poll local counters, you could then push them from your instances to pretty much anywhere you want: SQL Azure, SQL Server (on premise), web service, email, etc. However, as Stuart says, this feels like reinventing the wheel.

The Diagnostic Monitor aggregates counters across all of your instances, letting you easily aggregate counter values across all of your web roles, for instance, or letting you drill down on a specific instance easily.

Not sure why you'd want to avoid a storage account for diagnostics. At $0.15/GB, it's going to have very low cost overhead, especially if you're only storing diagnostic data. Plus, 3rd party monitoring tools (such as [AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com/AzureWatch)) need to pull counters from your storage account.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but I don't believe the current API allows you access to this data.

If you need access to performance counters, you could add your own collection service - but this feels like reinventing the wheel a little.

You could, of course, always get your web roles and your hosted service to all talk to a storage account - one that the outside system knows nothing about.